# How to compare a column values to see if the value is same except the ending of that value

Tags: mysql, sql

As you can see in the below picture, for the records 1 and 2, TPSL_SRNO value is same except for the ending. How can I take out the records which have this issue as it is causing up the quantities to double up.

```
Location_code   DocType   Date        TPSL_SRNO
---  ------------------------------------------------------
020027200000404   PSL   20180830    S2421100-1-0-5
020027200000404   PSL   20180830    S2421100-1-0-5-7200000404
020027200000404   PSL   20180830    S2421300-1-100-0
020027200000404   PSL   20180830    S2421300-1-100-0-7200000404
020027200000404   PSL   20180830    S2438600-1-45-0
020027200000404   PSL   20180830    S2438600-1-45-0-7200000404
```

[image]

Comment: Always the same pattern, skip dash number 4 and the rest of the value?

Comment: Plus, its my actual data and not any dummy.

Comment: I added text now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the result you hope to get. It's hard to guess from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Return a row if there are no *other* row (`<>`) with a TPSL_SRNO with the same start.

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.TPSL_SRNO like concat(t2.TPSL_SRNO, '%')
                    and t1.TPSL_SRNO <> t2.TPSL_SRNO)
```

Answer (score 0):

the will show you all the rows which have a long alternative in the TPSL_SRNO colum.

```sql
select t1.* from YOUR_TABLE t1, YOUR_TABLE t2
where t1.TPSL_SRNO != t2.TPSL_SRNO
and t1.TPSL_SRNO like concat(t2.TPSL_SRNO, '%')
```

Comment: Does MySQL support ANSI SQL `||` concatenation?

Comment: || in mysql is shortcut for or.